# How to identify is loged in user is a community user or portal user

Tags: partner-portal, partner-communities

I have created a managed package, in which I am displaying Chatter feeds for the logged in user. I want this feed to be displayed only for community users, not for portal users, so I want to hide the component for portal users. How can I identify if the logged in user is a community user or portal user?

Comment: Check with profile.name =  'Customer profile 1 name'.

Answer (score 4):

A community user can be a portal user. Communities supports several different user types (standard, portal, etc.). The same organization can have a community and a portal running side by side with the same user being able to login to both.

It sounds like what you want to know is "How can I tell if I'm in a community or not"?

To do that, you can use this Apex method:

```
public boolean inCommunity() {
   return Network.getNetworkId() != null;
}
```

Network is the API name for communities. For more information on the Network class check out the doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_network.htm

Comment: Yes but i want to know whether the user have loged as portal user or community user. I want to identity which how he has login.

Comment: a community user is a portal user